# cellClicked don't call function AgGrid Angular 2

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I want do "click" in my cell and show console.log, but this function doesn't run:

```
  headerName: 'Id',
  field: 'id',
  cellClicked: function() {
          console.log('asssaasas');
  }
```

I did click in my cell the AgGRID but in html5.console I don't show nothing....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you are adding `cellClicked` event at column level - within `ColDef`.

It doesn't work that way. It's a grid level event.

```
<ag-grid-angular #agGrid class="ag-fresh"
   ..... 
    (cellClicked)="onCellClicked($event)"
   ....
 >
</ag-grid-angular>
```

And within your component, write the function to handle this.

```
onCellClicked($event: CellClickedEvent) {
    console.log('asssaasas');
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I only want onclick in first cell, I don't want in anyone cell.. because I thinked  cellClicked in field 'id' . Can I do this ?

Comment: You can keep a check in `onCellClicked` -  I think you can get the column name from argument - `$event.colDef.id` or `$event.colDef.name` or something. And perform the action you want if the condition is fulfilled