# onCellClicked only first Cell AgGrid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I want get datas only the first column, or I know index the column,AgGrid Angular2.

I'm using

```
cellClicked
```

html

```
(cellClicked)="onCellClicked(event)"
```

component.ts

```
onCellClicked(event) {
    console.log('(event', event);
}
```

**The problem is that I can "click" in all rows...**
But I want can only do click in the first column or with if() know indexCell and if It is cell == 0 ...

Comment: Similar to [Ans: cellClicked don't call function AgGrid Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50488621/1417185) - just add check for the first column in the event handler

Answer (score 6):

```
onCellClicked(event){
  if (event.column.getColId() === 'your first column id') {
     // do your stuff here
  }
}
```